# Redirect Loop Error when using the Header function in PHP

Tags: php, loops, redirect, header, redirect-loop

I am having trouble with a redirecting a user to a certain page. I keep getting an error of "redirect loop". I know what this is, unfortunately, I do not know how to fix it. Here is my code $ setup.

```
//Check to see if the account is 'Active'
if (isset($_SESSION['inactive']) && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != 'account-balance.php') {
    if ($_SESSION['active'] != 'Yes') {
        $_SESSION['inactive'] = TRUE;
        header('Location: account-balance.php');
    }
}
```

This code is in a "header.php" include file that is included on every page. What I am wanting to do is check whether or now a users account is active. If it is not active, redirect to the account-balance.php page. Any link they click on, I simply want it to redirect them back to the account-balance.php page until they make their payment. Is this possible to do?

Comment: What is the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` on the account-balance page? Looks like it's not `account-balance.php`.

Comment: @Fred yes, it is above my code above

Comment: @MarkParnell I cannot seem to find out because when I try to echo it out, it still gives me the "redirect loop" error

Comment: @MarkParnell, it is showing the whole relative path such as /sandbox/pages/account-balance.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It is suppose to be basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) to get just the current page name.